# Steps for requests-html to parse more than one tag/class in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-requests, html-parsing

**Problem Introduction**
Language version: Python 3.8
Operating system: Windows 10
Any other relevant software: Jupyter Notebook and html-requests

Context:
I am following along with [this tutorial on parsing websites with requests-html.](https://youtu.be/5u391bX9FVE?t=1049)

**Problem statement:**

Goal:
My goal is to learn more by applying his code on a more difficult website (stackoverflow, for example.) I successfully isolated the 'div' tag/class using the code below. I now intend to sort everything on stackoverflow's recent questions page that is labeled div to find the 'question-summary' and somehow isolate the question ID.

Expected outcome:

- I want to isolate the question ID, save the associated html page for that unique question, and read each html page for each question that are in the first 3 pages (150 questions) of the most recent questions posted.

**Problem:**
At the 17:29 in the video, he points out that the tag/class he using a selector on was only used once and he would "need to go back to the drawing board" if it was used more than once.

I am trying to search for something relating to either 'id' or question-summary-#' . I am not sure what I am searching for but I know that there will be more than one. **What is the next step**?

**Example  result of current code:**

```
<Element 'div' class=('question-summary',) id='question-summary-64050283'>,
```

Things I have tried:
**Current code:**

```
import datetime
import requests
import requests_html
from requests_html import HTML
from importlib import reload
import sys
reload(sys)

now=datetime.datetime.now()
month=now.month
day=now.day
year=now.year
hour=now.hour
minute=now.minute
second=now.second

def url_to_txt(url, filename="world.html", save=False):
    r=requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        html_text=r.text
        if save:
            with open(f"world-{month}-{day}-{year}-{hour}-{minute}-{second}.html", 'w') as f:
                f.write(html_text)
        return html_text
    return ""

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2'

html_text = url_to_txt(url)

r_html=HTML(html=html_text)
table_class = "div"
r_table = r_html.find(table_class)

print(r_table)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: on that page, there are 50 `<div>` elements with an `id` attribute which has an attribute value of `question-summary-xxxxx`. As one of your steps, are you trying to get to these 50 values?

Comment: @JackFleeting Apologies. Yes, I am trying to first isolate these ~50 'xxxxx' values, then for each value, open the link.

Comment: @JackFleeting using `table_class = ".question-summary"` i was able to extract: `<Element 'div' class=('question-summary',) id='question-summary-64246258'>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing specifically on getting the `question-summary-xxx` values from the `id` attributes, you can try something like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&pagesize=50'

r = session.get(url)
targets = r.html.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id,"question-summary-")]/@id')

print(targets)
```

Output:

```
['question-summary-64248540',
 'question-summary-64248536',
 'question-summary-64248535',
 'question-summary-64248530',
...]

etc.
```